# sugarcrm invalid credentials for local instancce

Tags: php, sugarcrm

**Scenario**

I have backup of our latest SugarCRM instance of Production which I want to run on local machine.
I've done setup of DB and have configured in config.php.

I'm using SugarCRM Enterprise, Version 9.3.0 (Build 113) (Winter '20)

**Errors**

Currently I'm getting following error on browser

```
Invalid Credentials No valid authentication for User.
```

And in console I'm getting

`http://crm93.aws09.<domain>.local/rest/v11_7/ping?platform=base 401 (Unauthorized)`

Though I'm getting 200 for following

```
http://crm93.aws09.<domain>.local/rest/v11_7/metadata/public?type_filter=&platform=base&module_dependencies=1
```

Comment: Are you using credentials that were valid in production when you made the backup?

Comment: Yes, they are still valid and I'm using same credentials.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with the credentials you're trying to use. My best guess would be to ask another admin user to log in on your local machine and change their password. Then you'll be able to log in as them.

Comment: Well I'm the only admin with that profile.

Comment: The next thing I'd try is to create a new admin profile with a known password in the online instance. Then create a new backup and set up a new local instance using this backup. Then hopefully you'll be able to log in using the new admin credentials.

Comment: You can also copy the content of user_hash (the column for the hashed password) from the DB-table users, from an installation that works.

Comment: Any errors on the sugarcrm.log file?